Error while calling lua chunk: Failed to load parser for language 'vimdoc'
I have installed neovim on my windows machine by following this repo- KickStart neovim
Getting an error while running commands like - :help, <space>+sf, etc
Error- Error detected while processing modelines[262]..FileType Autocommands for "*"..function <SNR>1_LoadFTPlugin[20]..script                                     C:\Program Files\Neovim\share\nvim\runtime\ftplugin\help.lua:                                                                                               E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load pa                                    rser for language 'vimdoc': uv_dlopen: no error                                                                                                             stack traceback:                                                                                                                                                    [C]: in function '_ts_add_language'                                                                                                                         ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: in function 'add'                                                                          ...m/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/languagetree.lua:111: in function 'new'                                                                          ...m Files/Neovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter.lua:41: in function '_create_parser'                                                                ...m Files/Neovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter.lua:108: in function 'get_parser'                                                                   ...m Files/Neovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter.lua:416: in function 'start'                                                                        ...rogram Files/Neovim/share/nvim/runtime/ftplugin/help.lua:2: in main chunk                                                                        Error detected while processing modelines[262]..FileType Autocommands for "*":                                                                              Error executing lua callback: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for                                     language 'vimdoc': uv_dlopen: no error                                                                                                                     stack traceback:                                                                                                                                                    [C]: in function '_ts_add_language'                                                                                                                         ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: in function 'add'                                                                          ...m/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/languagetree.lua:111: in function 'new'                                                                          ...m Files/Neovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter.lua:41: in function '_create_parser'                                                                ...m Files/Neovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter.lua:108: in function 'get_parser'                                                                   ...m Files/Neovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter.lua:416: in function 'start'                                                                        ...a/lazy/nvim-treesitter/lua/nvim-treesitter/highlight.lua:20: in function 'attach'                                                                        ...ata/lazy/nvim-treesitter/lua/nvim-treesitter/configs.lua:509: in function 'attach_module'                                                                ...ata/lazy/nvim-treesitter/lua/nvim-treesitter/configs.lua:532: in function 'reattach_module'                                                              ...ata/lazy/nvim-treesitter/lua/nvim-treesitter/configs.lua:133: in function <...ata/lazy/nvim-treesitter/lua/nv                                    im-treesitter/configs.lua:132>

Attached the error message
enter image description here
Errors found on running :checkhealth command - 

The following errors have been detected: ~
- ERROR bash(highlights): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'bash': uv_dlopen: no error
  bash(highlights) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\bash\highlights.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'bash': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR bash(locals): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'bash': uv_dlopen: no error
  bash(locals) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\bash\locals.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'bash': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR bash(folds): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'bash': uv_dlopen: no error
  bash(folds) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\bash\folds.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'bash': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR bash(injections): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'bash': uv_dlopen: no error
  bash(injections) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\bash\injections.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'bash': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR c(highlights): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'c': uv_dlopen: no error
  c(highlights) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\c\highlights.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'c': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR c(locals): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'c': uv_dlopen: no error
  c(locals) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\c\locals.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'c': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR c(folds): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'c': uv_dlopen: no error
  c(folds) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\c\folds.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'c': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR c(indents): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'c': uv_dlopen: no error
  c(indents) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\c\indents.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'c': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR c(injections): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'c': uv_dlopen: no error
  c(injections) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\c\injections.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'c': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR diff(highlights): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'diff': uv_dlopen: no error
  diff(highlights) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\diff\highlights.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'diff': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR diff(folds): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'diff': uv_dlopen: no error
  diff(folds) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\diff\folds.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'diff': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR diff(injections): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'diff': uv_dlopen: no error
  diff(injections) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\diff\injections.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'diff': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR html(highlights): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'html': uv_dlopen: no error
  html(highlights) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\html_tags\highlights.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'html': uv_dlopen: no error
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\html\highlights.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'html': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR html(locals): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'html': uv_dlopen: no error
  html(locals) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\html\locals.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'html': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR html(folds): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'html': uv_dlopen: no error
  html(folds) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\html\folds.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'html': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR html(indents): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'html': uv_dlopen: no error
  html(indents) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\html_tags\indents.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'html': uv_dlopen: no error
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\html\indents.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'html': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR html(injections): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'html': uv_dlopen: no error
  html(injections) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\html_tags\injections.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'html': uv_dlopen: no error
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\html\injections.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'html': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR lua(highlights): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'lua': uv_dlopen: no error
  lua(highlights) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\lua\highlights.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'lua': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR lua(locals): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'lua': uv_dlopen: no error
  lua(locals) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\lua\locals.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'lua': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR lua(folds): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'lua': uv_dlopen: no error
  lua(folds) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\lua\folds.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'lua': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR lua(indents): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'lua': uv_dlopen: no error
  lua(indents) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\lua\indents.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'lua': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR lua(injections): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'lua': uv_dlopen: no error
  lua(injections) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\lua\injections.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'lua': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR luadoc(highlights): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'luadoc': uv_dlopen: no error
  luadoc(highlights) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\luadoc\highlights.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'luadoc': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR markdown(highlights): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'markdown': uv_dlopen: no error
  markdown(highlights) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\markdown\highlights.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'markdown': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR markdown(folds): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'markdown': uv_dlopen: no error
  markdown(folds) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\markdown\folds.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'markdown': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR markdown(indents): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'markdown': uv_dlopen: no error
  markdown(indents) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\markdown\indents.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'markdown': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR markdown(injections): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'markdown': uv_dlopen: no error
  markdown(injections) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\markdown\injections.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'markdown': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR markdown_inline(highlights): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'markdown_inline': uv_dlopen: no error
  markdown_inline(highlights) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\markdown_inline\highlights.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'markdown_inline': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR markdown_inline(injections): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'markdown_inline': uv_dlopen: no error
  markdown_inline(injections) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\markdown_inline\injections.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'markdown_inline': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR query(highlights): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'query': uv_dlopen: no error
  query(highlights) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\query\highlights.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'query': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR query(locals): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'query': uv_dlopen: no error
  query(locals) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\query\locals.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'query': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR query(folds): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'query': uv_dlopen: no error
  query(folds) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\query\folds.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'query': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR query(indents): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'query': uv_dlopen: no error
  query(indents) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\query\indents.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'query': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR query(injections): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'query': uv_dlopen: no error
  query(injections) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\query\injections.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'query': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR vim(highlights): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vim': uv_dlopen: no error
  vim(highlights) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\vim\highlights.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vim': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR vim(locals): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vim': uv_dlopen: no error
  vim(locals) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\vim\locals.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vim': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR vim(folds): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vim': uv_dlopen: no error
  vim(folds) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\vim\folds.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vim': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR vim(injections): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vim': uv_dlopen: no error
  vim(injections) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\vim\injections.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vim': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR vimdoc(highlights): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vimdoc': uv_dlopen: no error
  vimdoc(highlights) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\vimdoc\highlights.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vimdoc': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR vimdoc(injections): ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vimdoc': uv_dlopen: no error
  vimdoc(injections) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Rituraj\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy\nvim-treesitter\queries\vimdoc\injections.scm", failed to load: ...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vimdoc': uv_dlopen: no error

I tried to solve by running commands like (but it has not worked ) -

:TSInstall vimdoc & :TSInstallSync vimdoc
:checkHealth

